# Ajax popop on panels flexible sider not working correctly

Tags: panels

I am trying to create a custom layout using the Panels flexible layout designer. When I try clicking on, for example, Row -> Add region to left, the modal popup pops up, but I get dialog box from my browser saying:

```
The requested page can not be found.
```

and then the ajax loading symbol stays like that forever, never loading the content into the layout designer modal box. This is the url its trying to reach:

```
http://[site-name]/admin/structure/pages/nojs/operation/page-front_page/handlers/page_front_page_panel_context/layout/move
```

Why am I having this issue? Is this something I should put on the Panels issue page, or is there something I can test to see if its wrong on my side? I don't see any javascript errors in the console, and don't see any issues in the network tab with the ajax call.

Comment: Are you on a secure page?  If so it might be because the url you're trying to reach is insecure...

Comment: try disable admin menu...

Comment: @Darvanen - my site is entirely http, so thats not the issue